# How to guess output in this case of for loop

Tags: c, loops

Why there is some output in one case and there is no output in another case?

```
int i;
for (;i;)
 {
  printf("Hello  ");
 }
```

Output= 
Hello Hello Hello Hello ....

---

```
int i=0;
for (;i;)
 {
  printf("Hello ");
 }
```

No output

Comment: Your question suggests you think `int i;` might start `i` with the value 0. That is not the case. When regular objects are defined inside functions (you do not show a function, but the `for` loop can only be inside a function), they are not automatically initialized. (FYI to the authors of the answers so far: Look beyond the first level of code in the question and think about what the author is thinking.) If an object is `static` because it is defined with `static` or is defined outside a function, it is initialized with zero (or the “zero” for its type, such as a null pointer).

Comment: What output where you expecting in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case *i* is not initialized so the behavior is undefined. In your case *i* has a non null value and the *for* turns without ending because its value never change producing these printing, but again that behavior is undefined.

In the second case *i* is 0  so the body of the *for* is never executed

`for (;i;)` is equivalent as `while(i)`

---

A variable is *not* initialized to 0 by default.

If you want to write for instance 5 times Hello you can do :

```
 int i;

 for (i = 5 ;i; --i)
 {
   printf("Hello  ");
 }
```

that code is equivalent to that one using a different notation/operator if that can helps you to understand :

```
 int i = 5;

 while (i != 0) {
   printf("Hello  ");
   i -= 1;
 }
```

and to add `putchar('\n');` after the loop to print a newline is not a bad idea too

Comment: The author likely does not know that `i` is not initialized in the first example, and this answer does not explain that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil really ?

Comment: Yes, really. Do you think somebody just asks about random code? There are reasons they ask. Commonly, a reason somebody asks why two things are different is their first thought is they would be the same. Why would these two pieces of code behave the same? They would if `int i` initialized `i` to zero, and not otherwise. Furthermore, it is a natural thought: Objects are initialized to zero (or equivalent) in many languages, and are initialized to zero in C if they are static. So thinking `i` is initialized to zero would explain why the OP asked the question.

Comment: Conversely, if OP knew `i` is uninitialized, why would they ask? They would know `i` has no defined value, so it would not be surprising to them that the behavior differs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok, thank you for the remark, I edited my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior since `i` has automatic storage duration and is never initialized.

This means that accessing the value at `i` is undefined behavior. If it happens to contain a non-zero value, then the `for` loop body will be perpetually true (since nothing in the loop changes the value of `i`).

The second example explicitly initializes `i` with the value of zero, which means that when used as a conditional statement it will be considered false.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2)

Comment: The author likely does not know that `i` is not initialized in the first example, and this answer does not explain that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I read your comment thread on bruno's answer and still find it difficult to apply that thinking to my answer, since I do mention why explicit initialization with zero removes the undefined behavior, and that `i` has automatic storage duration.

Comment: Your answer says that `i` “is never initialized.” It does not say why that is true. Under the rules in the C standard, sometimes `int i;` would initialize `i`, and sometimes it would not. So, if you are teaching somebody who does not know that `i` is not initialized, you should explain the rules about it. You should teach them how to know whether `i` is initialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

i is uninitialised, so in some cases, i contains a non -zero number, so ;i; is true, so the condition always runs as true.

Always initialise your values if they are integers or chars. it costs you literally nothing to do in terms of performance and it saves so much work later hunting down bugs.

Comment: The author likely does not know that `i` is not initialized in the first example, and this answer does not explain that. Additionally, the behavior with uninitialized objects is more complicated than containing some unspecified value.

Answer (score 0):

The first example has undefined behaviour.

The loop part of the code is functionally equivalent to:

```
while (i) {
{
    printf("Hello ");
}
```

If `i` is set to 0, execution will never get to the `printf`. If `i` is never initialized, it could contain any value. If it happened to be 0, it would never run, but if it is non-zero, the loop will run forever.

Comment: This answer does not say why the first example has undefined behavior or why `i` is not initialized in the first example.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  `i` is simply not initialized. It's a true statement that has a clear meaning in C. There's no "why" to `i` not being initialized, it just is.

Comment: There is a “why”. The rules of the C standard say some things are initialized in a certain way and that some things are not initialized. These rules should be explained, at least to the extent applicable to the question. Additionally, using an uninitialized object is not always undefined behavior. There are specific rules about that.